# PHP - Can I post to different pages depending on data submitted in form?

Tags: php, post

I'd like to know if it's possible to change the page data will be posted to according on the selections made on the page.
For example, depending on a dropdown, a radio button array etc...

I understand it can be done using javascript, any other options? I'm using PHP and the page data is being submitted to is declared in the "action" property on my form.

Comment: well if youre using a MVC framework you would just post to a controller and let the controller decide where and what to do with the data.

Comment: have you tried the function.. output_add_rewrite_var('formVariable1','formVariable2')

Answer (score 0):

Remember that your PHP is built server side, if you want client interaction you will have to re-submit the page. ie. onchange=submit allowing you to use the form data to tell the PHP what to show.

It's pretty standard, JavaScript & AJAX just make it more efficient but essentially its the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To show another option:

Well, you can decide once the form is posted:

```php
if ($_POST['some column'] == 'some expected value') {
    header("Location: http://host/page1.php");
} elseif ($_POST['some other column'] == 'some expected value') {
    header("Location: http://host/page2.php");
} elseif ($_POST['some other other column'] == 'some expected value') {
    header("Location: http://host/page3.php");
}
```

Let the form post to itself or a certain page.. then let that page perform the decision making  part.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the submit button from something like

```
<input type="submit" ...>
```

to

```
<input type="button" onclick="doSubmit(this.form);" ...>
```

and use something like

```
function doSubmit(frm) {

  //whatever

  frm.action=<your page address here>

  frm.submit()
}
```